# Python: Multiple choice questioning code

Tags: python, variables, input

```
print "Do you want to be (A) begginner, (B) interidate or (Other) advanced?"
input = level
if level == "A":
    ...
elif level == "B":
    ...
else :
    ...
```

This turns up with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/*****/Maths.py", line 4, in <module>
    input = level
NameError: name 'level' is not defined
```

I'm new to python so sorry if this is obvious but I couldn't find a solution looking through guides.

Answer (score 2):

You should use raw_input in the following way:

```
level = raw_input("Do you want to be (A) begginner, (B) intermediate or (Other) advanced? ")
if level == "A":
    print "A"
elif level == "B":
    print "B"
else :
    print "default"
```

`raw_input` will return a string while `input` will try to eval whatever the user passed in the command line and assign it to the specified variable.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2, you need to use

```
level=raw_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

It comes in the 2nd line of you're provided code: `input = level`
Where you're saying "Make input equal to level"

it should be:

```
level = input("Do you want to be (A) begginner, (B) interidate or (Other) advanced?")
...
```

thus you are setting the variable `level` to equal whatever `input` is from the user.